# website fatal error after wordpress upgrade

Tags: wordpress

I get this error after upgrading to the last wordpress version

Fatal error: Call to undefined function is_posts_page() in /home/modernis/public_html/wp-content/themes/room09/home.php on line 19

this is the site with the problem: http://modernist.ro/

Comment: that should probably be is_home(); You can change it manually, but I suggest updating the theme. If there's no update, change the theme.

Comment: any other solution beside changing the theme?..

Comment: Updating the theme, or manually fixing the theme.

Comment: any ideas on how exactly i can do that?

Comment: You will have to edit the theme - however this sugests that the theme is not compatible with newer WordPress and as such fixing one bug might just then reveal many more. So are best advised to see if there is a theme update, if not you really should find a new theme or update the old one. If you want to update the old one and need help paste in the code of home.php (specifically the code around line 19) cheers :)